# Reflect Type comparison

Tags: go, reflection

I want to ensure that the type of `map` keys is `string`. `Key()` method returns `Type` and I'm not sure what is the right way to check if it's `string`. The only thing came to my mind is:

```
if v.Type().Key() == reflect.TypeOf("") {
    fmt.Print("It is string")
}
```

Is it the right way?

Comment: Are you looking for Kind?

Comment: @Volker As I said, I just want to ensure that key is a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you did reports if the key type is "exactly" `string`.

But for example if the key type would be a custom type having `string` as its underlying type, like in this example:

```
type mystr string
m := map[mystr]int{}
```

Then the key type would not be equal to `reflect.TypeOf("")`.

It's up to you if this is what you want. If you do want to accept the above map types too, you may check the *kind* of the key if it equals to `reflect.String` like this:

```
if v.Type().Key() == reflect.TypeOf("") {
    fmt.Print("It is string")
}

if v.Type().Key().Kind() == reflect.String {
    fmt.Print("It is string kind")
}
```

For the above `map[mystr]int`, this is the output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XKNV5GOw7GG)):

```
It is string kind
```

(The key is not of type `string`, but it is of kind `string`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the `Kind` of the key and confront it with kind enumerations in `reflect` package like `reflect.String` as in:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    obj := make(map[string]interface{})

        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(obj).Key().Kind() == reflect.String) // It will print true
}
```

See this [Go Playground snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/ilNAI7e-0q_A) if you want to try it.